# Forms submission on select with a page having multiple select forms

Tags: javascript

if there is a page with multiple select forms on it as below and the form needs to be submitted using js (but not inline), then is there a simple way to achieve it using just one function?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Toyota</option>
    <option value="2">Nissan</option>
</select> 
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="trucks" id="trucks">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">TATA</option>
    <option value="2">Nissan</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

If I had to do it in line, it would be simply

```
onchange = 'this.form.submit();
```

How do I do this using a js file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
});
```

EDIT:
As per your request, if I understood you correctly:
1) Put the code above as is in the `submit.js` file.
2) In your html/php file reference the script by `<script src="submit.js"></script>`

Comment: Could you please also show how to invoke the onchange function if the code snippet you provided is in a file named submit.js. Presently I am echoing using php which is somewhat like this : `echo "<form action='' method='post'>
<select name='trucks' id='trucks'> onchange = 'this.form.submit'
    <option value=''>Choose</option> ... "`

Comment: Exactly as I have been trying to get it to work but it seems not to detect the the onchange event. This is what I am doing:-    `onchange = '<script src=submit.js></script>' `. but the file does not trigger.

Comment: You can't load a script this way. :) Put it before the opening `<form>` tag. Or better yet, in the `<head>` of your html page.

Answer (score 1):

You can just target the selects and submit the parent form.
Preferably you'd add classes to those selects, but you could just get all selects

```
[].slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName('select') ).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('change', function() { this.form.submit() });
});
```

Comment: Hi adeneo ! Thanks for the reply which I think is too complex for me and so I chose to go with the simpler reply of timenomad. If I could I would have a voted for both of them to be best.

Comment: @Ajoo - no problem, the only difference is that this answer doesn't use jQuery, which is simply because you didn't tag your question with jQuery, only with javascript.